# In Grails, how to change environment variables with Ant?

Tags: grails, ant, build

I'm pretty sure this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the correct answer after spending quite some time googling... :)

Anyway, in our build server, we have two (2) different versions of Grails and Java running; one is 1.3.3 with JDK 1.5 while the other is 1.3.6 with JDK 1.6. Now, when building/creating the WAR file for these 2 projects, we pretty much need to switch the environment variables for GRAILS_HOME and JAVA_HOME automatically via the ANT script... for which I am a total noob >.<

Consider:

```
...
<target name="clean">
...
</target>

<target name="war" depends="clean">
...
</target>
...
```

If I set the env't variables at the time `clean` is being done, it will, of course, not be the same when `war` is run (I've tried using batch files and even if it worked, it was messy and not DRY... hence, I'm looking for alternatives).

Now, I've seen `macrodef` being tossed around a few forums but I can't seem to get a clear sample on how to do it for this case. Any suggestions on what I can do or some pointers?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a similar use case and I'm also googling for the same. Till now I've got these, I will try these reaching office tomorrow.

1. ```
   <java classname="ShowJavaVersion" classpath="."
   jvm="path-to-java14-home/bin/java" fork="true"
   taskname="java1.4">
   ```
2. ```
   <property environment="env"/>
   <exec ...>
       <env key="PATH" path="${env.PATH}:${basedir}/bin"/>
   </exec>
   ```
3. Executing batch file.